# Why pass a value to a template instead of supplying it in a function call?

Tags: c++, templates

As I'm going along learning C++, there is a concept that I am not able to fully grasp and comprehend the reasoning behind the mechanics.  And that topic is: Function templates and the passing of arguments at compile time, rather than run time.

What I want to know is, the reasoning behind the design in passing the values of --lets say for example-- an int value, at compile time.  I'm thinking it was possible that the developers of C++ could've allowed the passing of value at run-time, but what I want to know is this -- The reasoning of choosing to pass the value of, lets say an int, during compile time.  Of course I'm talking about function templates like this one :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
T fixed_multiply (T val)
{
  return val * N;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << fixed_multiply<int,2>(10) << '\n';
  std::cout << fixed_multiply<int,3>(10) << '\n';
}
```

To my knowledge, the int value assigned in the calling of the template function (in this case the <2> and <3>) are calculated at compile time.  What is the reasoning behind the design of these mechanics?  I understand it is to create a different instance of each function, one that multiplies by 2, and one that multiplies by 3, respectively.  Because of that, it cannot be passed a variable, it must be passed a constant.

But why is this necessary?  I feel that the designers could've allowed run time execution, so that the values passed to it could be variables, but obviously the designers thought it would be better this way.

Thanks.

Comment: Templates are instantiated at compile time, and the more you can calculate at compile time the less you have to calculate at run time (so your program should run faster).

Comment: Yeah, but I thought the point of templates was to prevent redundant coding.  Unless the designers wanted to add another feature on top of the prevention of redundancy, optimization?

Comment: Take a look at `template meta-programming`; that really takes it to the extreme. For example, you could calculate the output of your program before it even runs by using templates. Templates will do whatever you tell them to do!

Comment: For a possibly better example, imagine you use many regex expressions. Those can all be parsed at compile time with Boost.Xpressive rather than each time your program starts. This saves start-up time and adds nice compile-time error checking.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes more optimizations are possible when one of the operands is a known constant.

For example, on the x86 architecture, a multiply by (constant) 3 can be implemented with the `LEA` instruction which runs much faster than `IMUL`.  Division of an unsigned integer variable by a constant power of two can be replaced by right bit-shift, (and modulo by bitwise-AND).

Comment: So the reasoning behind it was strictly to allow more options for lower level optimizations?

Comment: @user3435157: I can only tell you advantages of this method, I can't reach into the designer's head and tell you what his reason was.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it does indeed improve performance on the machine level.  Your description was the most helpful

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have to multiply by two all the elements of a vector and you have an algorithm that transforms all the elements of a vector.

The algorithm can be customized with a function that takes a *one argument*

But you have multiply that takes to arguments... so you can bind one argument to a contact (at compile time) and effectively create a single argument function

Comment: @user3435157 well, I'd say is adaptation of APIs

Comment: nice example.. instead of calling the the second argument x amount of times, you can have a function that only needs 1 argument, potentially saving an exponential amount of resources..

Answer (score 1):

The main reason someone passes a integer value or a float value(rarely) or whatever as a template arg, is because they represent different types in their problems. And they want to have reusable methods and algorithms that operate on these types.

From a design standpoint, checkout [Boost Multi Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) as an example. This is a system that's designed to support n-dimensional arrays. So by nature when you define,

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_3d;
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_2d;
```

they're two completely different types. Someone can write a special iterator that takes a `multi_array<type, int>`, without having to redefine it for the 2d and 3d cases.

There're possibly code bases which optimize their functions the way you listed, but those are exceptions. Optimization is not the prime motive when templatizing anything, but having a modular, reusable, generic code is.

Comment: floats as template arguments is not a standard feature.